# trying to count mysql data between time1 and time2

Tags: mysql, datetime, time, between

I have a database table `'email_log'` which would be filled with information as:
user, subject and opened (as datetime)

What I need is a new query from which I can see how many rows contain the column 'opened' between `08:00` and `09:00`.

What I had didn't work:

```
SELECT count(*) as count FROM email_log WHERE opened BETWEEN '00:08:00' AND '00:09:00';
```

Does anyone know the trick?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql: get record count between two date-time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786649/mysql-get-record-count-between-two-date-time)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to include the entire format for the `datetime` - since it's got both a date and a time.

See: [mysql: get record count between two date-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786649/mysql-get-record-count-between-two-date-time)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT count(*) as count FROM email_log WHERE 
opened BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('5/15/2012', '%c/%e/%Y') 
AND STR_TO_DATE('5/15/2012', '%c/%e/%Y'); // date only

SELECT count(*) as count FROM email_log WHERE 
opened BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('8:06:26 AM', '%r') 
AND STR_TO_DATE('8:06:26 AM', '%r'); // time only
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT 
FROM email_log 
WHERE  DATE_FORMAT(opened,"%H:%i:%S")  > '00:08:00' AND  DATE_FORMAT(opened,"%H:%i:%S")  < '00:09:00'
```