# How to use the BETWEEN and LIKE operator with two wild card characters

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I am using the report viewer asp.net 2010 for generating the report...what i want is i am displaying the lost book record between the start-date and end-date. for that in the table adaption configuration wizard.. i am writing the following query... but giving the error...

**first try**

```
SELECT book_id, ah_id, ah_name, issue_date, return_date, status, issue_id 
FROM issue_book
return_date  BETWEEN ( LIKE CONCAT ('%', @stardate ,'%' ? '%', @enddate ,'%' ))
```

**second try**

```
SELECT book_id, ah_id, ah_name, issue_date, return_date, status, issue_id 
FROM issue_book
return_date  BETWEEN ( LIKE CONCAT ('%', @stardate ,'%' AND '%', @enddate ,'%' ))
```

**third try**

```
SELECT book_id, ah_id, ah_name, issue_date, return_date, status, issue_id 
FROM issue_book
return_date  BETWEEN ( LIKE CONCAT ('%', @stardate ,'%' '%', @enddate ,'%' ))
```

Comment: if it is a date field you should use > and <  with no wild cards

Comment: see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786649/mysql-get-record-count-between-two-date-time