# Get reservations by time

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with MySQL, I am trying to get all reservations where the starttime is larger than '16:42' but smaller than '18:42'. I tried this, but when i use '15:42' instead of '16:42' i still got the same result.

```
SELECT     * 
FROM       `tables` 
INNER JOIN reservation_table 
ON         `tables`.`id` = reservation_table.table_id 
INNER JOIN reservations 
ON         reservations.id = reservation_table.reservation_id 
INNER JOIN customers 
ON         customers.id = reservations.customer_id 
WHERE  `date` = '2016-11-02' 
   AND ( starttime <= '19:42' 
         AND starttime >= '16:42' )
```

[image: This is the result of the query]

Comment: Why not combine date and time into one field: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786649/mysql-get-record-count-between-two-date-time

Comment: which data type is the column starttime ?

Comment: Its the time datatype

Answer (score 1):

could be you have some conversion issue .. try using an explicit conversion

```
SELECT     * 
FROM       `tables` 
INNER JOIN reservation_table 
ON         `tables`.`id` = reservation_table.table_id 
INNER JOIN reservations 
ON         reservations.id = reservation_table.reservation_id 
INNER JOIN customers 
ON         customers.id = reservations.customer_id 
WHERE  `date` = '2016-11-02' 
   AND ( starttime <= str_to_date('19:42', '%H:%i' )
         AND starttime >= str_to_date('16:42' , '%H:%i'))
```

Comment: what mean doesn't work .. you have error? .. wrong result .? . no result?

Comment: I dont get any result, if i use str_to_date(). Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: instead  without str_to_date  you get a result but the result don't change when you change the time string?

Comment: When i use str_to_date, i dont get a result whatever i fill in. When i dont use str_to_date, i get a result, but when i set the time 15:42 instead of 16:42 (in the query.) I still get a result

Comment: well you shoul update your question  adding the schema of the related table .. a proper data sample and the expected  result ..

Comment: I have also update the answer because the sintax of the  str_to_date format  was wrong.. (missing %)

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

If `starttime` and `endtime` columns are in `TIME` format then this queries should solve your problem:

Because as mysql documentation say *"If the NO_ZERO_DATE or NO_ZERO_IN_DATE SQL mode is enabled, zero dates or part of dates are disallowed."* you may need to execute this query first:

```
SET sql_mode = '';
```

then the second one (if starttime and endtime columns are in TIME format):

```
SELECT     *
FROM       `tables` 
INNER JOIN reservation_table 
ON         `tables`.`id` = reservation_table.table_id 
INNER JOIN reservations 
ON         reservations.id = reservation_table.reservation_id 
INNER JOIN customers 
ON         customers.id = reservations.customer_id 
WHERE  `date` = '2016-11-02'
AND ( starttime <= str_to_date('19:42', '%H:%i')
    AND starttime >= str_to_date('16:42' , '%H:%i'))
```

but if these columns are not in that format do:

```
SELECT     *
FROM       `tables` 
INNER JOIN reservation_table 
ON         `tables`.`id` = reservation_table.table_id 
INNER JOIN reservations 
ON         reservations.id = reservation_table.reservation_id 
INNER JOIN customers 
ON         customers.id = reservations.customer_id 
WHERE  `date` = '2016-11-02'
AND ( str_to_date(starttime, '%H:%i') <= str_to_date('19:42', '%H:%i')
    AND str_to_date(starttime, '%H:%i') >= str_to_date('16:42' , '%H:%i'))
```