# Mysql select items that occur a number of times in given date range

Tags: mysql, sql

[Customer table with purchases in a date range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znZHg.jpg)

Having some challenge doing this.

1. Select all customers that made more than 2 purchases in an hour
   starting from a given datetime eg.2016-01-01.13:00:00
2. Select all customers that made more than 2 purchases in a a day(24
   hours) starting from a given datetime eg. 2016-01-01.15:30:05

   ```
   Select count(name) from cust_table where count(name) 
   IN (BETWEEN (2016-01-01.13:00:00, 2016-01-01.14:00:00))
   ```

Comment: The reason to study is to learn. If we do the homework for you, you won't learn much.

Comment: Not a homework. Actual implementation . I'm stuck with the sql part

Comment: WHERE count(name) >1 AND BETWEEN(2016-01-01.13:00:00, 2016-01-01.14:00:00)?

Comment: Or if you need to after a datetime: AND "date" > 2016-01-01.13:00:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the identifiers (usernames or ID or so) for all users who have made more than two purchases. Something like the following should work:

```
SELECT name FROM purchases GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(name) > 2
```

To get such rows where the purchases were made between some dates, just add a `WHERE` clause, so it becomes something like this

```
SELECT name FROM purchases WHERE pdate BETWEEN (2016-01-01.13:00:00) AND (2016-01-01.14:00:00) GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(name) > 2
```

What this does is group the table rows by name with purchases between the specified dates. It then filters the groups using the `HAVING COUNT(name) > 2` clause to retrieve only rows that appear more than twice.

Comment: thanks. datetime value gives sql error near '13:00:00. But when I do only date it works. meaning we cannot find between datetimes?

Comment: Check this answer for the correct format of datetime: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5786722/1256113