# Get records based on date column value and time range arguments

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'd like to return records in a MySQL database based on whether the record date falls in between a time range (using PDO).

Time Range:

```
$rangeStart = "17-Jul-18 04:45 pm";
$rangeEnd = "17-Jul-18 05:30 pm";
```

Method:

```
public function getForTokenIDAddressAndDateRange($token_id, $address, $rangeStart, $rangeEnd) {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `{$this->table}` WHERE `token_id` = ? AND `address` = ? AND `date` <= ? AND `date` >= ?";
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([$token_id, $address, strtotime($rangeStart), strtotime($rangeEnd)]);

}
```

Example "date" value from a record:

```
17-Jul-18 5:04 pm
```

How can I make the above method work properly? I believe I need to convert the "date" column value to a timestamp, but not sure how. thx!

Comment: does your date field in timestamp?

Comment: no its a varchar currently

Comment: I just fixed it, sorry that was an error only here on SO

Comment: there is something wrong in your `execute`. `[]` shouldn't have used.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that as well. How about converting the date column value to a timestamp? I think thats the last step now. thank you again

Comment: It's quite difficult. Check this link. https://community.teradata.com/t5/UDA/convert-varchar-to-timestamp/td-p/32302

Comment: What happens when you run that query directly with those values?  Get that working first without php. Covert field to datetime if needed. Going to look at this tomorrow as I am curious how to solve.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786649/mysql-get-record-count-between-two-date-time

Comment: I think the values you pass in will have to be military time instead of am/pm. And your mysql column needs to be datetime.

Comment: `date` <= ? AND `date` >= ?  weird condition.

Comment: Always store data using the correct data type - otherwise there's not much point using SQL at all.